# 'Lossy Conversion' vs. 'Loss of precision'

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Can someone please explain/link any documentation that can differentiate between

> Possible Loss of Precision Error

and

> Lossy Conversion.

I cannot understand which error will occur under what circumstance.
Any explanation with examples is deeply appreciated

Comment: Isn't the question too broad? Can you provide some context?

Comment: The question i have is simple, what is the reason for getting the following : 'Lossy Conversion' and 'Possible Loss of Precision'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is the end of the number which gets chopped off:

- Lossy conversion returns least-significant bits. It is described in [JLS Sec 5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

  > A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

  It is something like converting an int to a byte: you simply get the 8 least-significant bits in this case:

  ```
  System.out.println((byte) 258); // 2
  ```
- Loss of precision returns most-significant bits. It is described in [JLS Sec 5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2):

  > A widening primitive conversion from int to float, or from long to float, or from long to double, may result in *loss of precision* - that is, the result may lose some of the least significant bits of the value.

  It is something like storing an int in a float which is too large to be represented accurately

  ```
  int i = (1 << 24) + 1;
  float f = i;
  System.out.println((int) f == i); // false, because precision is lost.
  ```

Comment: can you please give me one more example on the second point.
Also, following up on the edit you just made, does the condition only apply when we try to convert from (byte, short,char,int, long) non decimal primitives to (float and double) decimal point primitives?

Comment: No, it is perfect. I just want to get an example on the same with data types that are not int and float.

Comment: @AshishSharma the quote from JLS specifically describes the types between which loss of precision can occur. Any other  example I would give would be some value, some type, as with the current example.

Comment: the second code 
`float f = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println((int) f == Integer.MAX_VALUE);` 
is still displaying TRUE

Comment: @AshishSharma try with `(1<<24)+1`.

Comment: Got false with **(1<<24)+1** , can u please tell me why that was not the case with **Integer.MAX_VALUE**

Answer (score 0):

You get possible loss of precision error when you try to cast such as double to int. You are trying to convert one primitive to another primitive but there is no enough space and you can get loss of your some bytes.

```
double x = 10.5;             // 8 bytes
int y = x;                   // 4 bytes ;  raises compilation error
```

You should look for the primitives [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)